# adding a text to beginning of a line based on input in the file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, tr

Hi I have a difficult ( at least for me ) task to do. I need to do the following:

Here is my input

```
host1
atetley 170.198.19.165 91 18 6 4198
NJPYNYFWD01 170.198.82.143 257 14 6 4749
NJTTKLFWD01 170.198.82.142 257 13 6 3993
host2
dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
host3
dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
fklotz 198.177.151.81 91 15 6 1829
ganthos 198.177.151.92 91 20 6 791
```

I need the following output

```
host1 atetley 170.198.19.165 91 18 6 4198
host1 NJPYNYFWD01 170.198.82.143 257 14 6 4749
host1 NJTTKLFWD01 170.198.82.142 257 13 6 3993
host2 dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
host3 dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
host3 fklotz 198.177.151.81 91 15 6 1829 
host3 ganthos 198.177.151.92 91 20 6 791
```

Not sure how to do this at all.  I do have a control on how to inject the hostname ( example host1 host host3 ) in the outpute file. So I can say put a unique identifier before each host like "uuu"

```
uuuhost1
atetley 170.198.19.165 91 18 6 4198
NJPYNYFWD01 170.198.82.143 257 14 6 4749
NJTTKLFWD01 170.198.82.142 257 13 6 3993
UUUhost2
dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
UUUhost3
dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
fklotz 198.177.151.81 91 15 6 1829
ganthos 198.177.151.92 91 20 6 791
```

But I still need the result like this. If adding a unique identifier helps. I can strip it later after the file mainpulation is over. Example take all the "UUU" out of the file

```
host1 atetley 170.198.19.165 91 18 6 4198
host1 NJPYNYFWD01 170.198.82.143 257 14 6 4749
host1 NJTTKLFWD01 170.198.82.142 257 13 6 3993
host2 dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
host3 dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
host3 fklotz 198.177.151.81 91 15 6 1829 
host3 ganthos 198.177.151.92 91 20 6 791
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk to print it:

```
awk 'NF==1{h=$1;next} {print h, $0}' file
host1 atetley 170.198.19.165 91 18 6 4198
host1 NJPYNYFWD01 170.198.82.143 257 14 6 4749
host1 NJTTKLFWD01 170.198.82.142 257 13 6 3993
host2 dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
host3 dfriel 198.177.151.69 91 14 6 2023
host3 fklotz 198.177.151.81 91 15 6 1829
host3 ganthos 198.177.151.92 91 20 6 791
```

Comment: Sorry the logic is as follow: Basically I cat the file then I have to tell it to find the first hostname ( host1). Once it finds it then it has to add host1 to whatever number of lines that comes after it  and before the next hostname "host2" is found. I don;t think a simple awk command achieves this?

Comment: That is exactly this command dies. Did you check the attached output and is it not matching your expected output?

Comment: lol :) @jaypal I see my typo now. You can run: `"echo ${comment/ies/oes}"`

Comment: Hi This is working .. Thanks anubhava ,, I checked it today as I had to do other work .. Thanks again. I still do know how this command works

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk 'NF==1{p=$1;next}$0=p FS$0' file
```

Comment: Hi kent. I don't thing this logic works for what I need to do. The hostnames ( host1 host2 host3 ) can be anything and in whatever order so where will it get the $1 names from . The logic has to find the host name inside of the file. They are not in any particular order

Comment: Hi The hosts name can be any-name and any length that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt :

```
awk '/^host/ {host=$1} NF>1{print host, $0}' <myfile
```

myfile containing

```
host1
atetley 170.198.19.165 91 18 6 4198
NJPYNYFWD01 170.198.82.143 257 14 6 4749
...
```

it does the following, for each line :

if the line begins with host (if it matches // a regular expression, ^host being : ^ starts with, host), assign the first field ($1) to the variable "host"

if the number of field is greater than 1 (NF>1), print the variable host, and the line ($0)

Answer (score 0):

in bash:

```
while read FIRST REST
do
    [ ${FIRST:0:4} = "host" ] && HOST="$FIRST" || echo "$HOST $FIRST $REST"
done <inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^\S+$/{h;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file
```

Save the hostname in the hold space and prepend it to non-hostname lines